# React routes not automatically updating when nested under 'smart' Redux container components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm trying to create an Electron app using React, React-router and Redux. What I'm finding is that my routing logic works absolutely fine when I'm nesting the switch/route logic under a purely presentational component (`Page`), but that I'm forced to refresh the page to see navigational changes if nested under a 'smart' container component.

Near the top of my React component hierarchy (right beneath `HashRouter`) I have a `Page`:

```
export default function Page (props) {
  return (
      <div className={`${styles.page}`}>
        <SideBar/>
        <DetailPane>{props.children}</DetailPane>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Here, `DetailPane` and `SideBar` are both container components wrapped around presentational components of the same name.

At startup (and during hot reloads), I create my React hierarchy using this function:

```
export default () => (
    <Router>
      <Page>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/txDefinitions/:definitionName/:fieldName' component={FieldPage}/>
          <Route exact path='/txDefinitions/:definitionName?' component={DefinitionPage}/>
          <Route exact path='/rxDefinitions/:definitionName?' component={DefinitionPage}/>
          <Route exact path='/'/>
          <Route component={Route404}/>
        </Switch>
      </Page>
    </Router>
```

This means that `<Switch>...</Switch>` gets nested underneath `<DetailPane>`.

If I try to navigate around my app (clicking links in the side bar), I won't actually see the detail pane render the new component until I force-reload the Electron app.

However, I find that routing works as expected if I omit `DetailPane` from `Page`:

```
export default function Page (props) {
  return (
      <div className={`${styles.page}`}>
        <SideBar/>
        {props.children}
      </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my React hierarchy *without* `DetailPane` (works fine):

[image]

Here is my React hierarchy *with* `DetailPane` (does not work right):

[image]

(Apologies for using images but I'm not sure if there's a way to copy from React devtools into clipboard - appears larger if opened in a new tab).

---

As I was writing this question, I realised this wouldn't be a huge issue for me because earlier refactoring had made the 'smart' version of `DetailPane` apparently obsolete. Using the purely presentational version of `DetailPane`
instead resolves this issue:

```
import * as React from 'react';
//import {DetailPane} from '../../containers'; // Smart/Redux
import {DetailPane} from '../../components'; // Dumb/presentational
import {SideBar} from '../../containers/';
const styles = require('./Page.scss');

export default function Page (props) {
  return (
      <div className={`${styles.page}`}>
        <SideBar/>
        <DetailPane>{props.children}</DetailPane>
      </div>
  );
}
```

However, I'm still curious *why* this doesn't work for the container component version. For reference, this is the container component version of `DetailPane`:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {DetailPane} from '../../components';

// TODO: delete this container?

function mapStateToProps (state): {} {
  return {};
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  // TODO.
  return {};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DetailPane);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `connect` HOC implements [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) logic so if the props don't change, the component doesn't update.

To prevent this from occurring, and have the component always render, you can override the `pure` option in the `connect` call.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, undefined, { pure: false })(DetailPane);
```

See the [react-redux API docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'm sticking with the presentational version for now but this is very useful to know in case I need to switch back later.